# Redirecting to a page in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4, uri

I wants to make a list page and add page 
for list page my route function is

```
Route::get('admin/auctionlist','AdminController@showAuctionList');
```

and controller is

```
public function showAuctionList(){
        $auctions = DB::table('auctionitems')
                        ->leftjoin('campaigns','campaigns.id','=','auctionitems.campId')
                        ->select('auctionitems.*','campaigns.title')
                        ->get();
        return View::make('admin/auctionlist')->with('auction',$auctions);
    }
```

it works fine and my url is
http://localhost/vishal/site/public/admin/auctionlist

And for my add page route is

```
Route::post('addAuction',function(){
    $obj = new AdminController() ;
    return $obj->addAuction();
});
```

controller is

```
public function addAuction(){
        AuctionModel::addAuctions(Input::except(array('_token')));
         return $this->showAuctionList();       
    }
```

It redirects to list page but url showing as 
http://localhost/vishal/site/public/addAuction
Aucually i want to the url as 
http://localhost/vishal/site/public/admin/auctionlist
how can i get it.?

Comment: Before you do anything please remove public from your url, to do that you should point your localhost to public folder of laravel. If you have other projects hosted on your localhost you may create a virtual host to do so

Comment: i have only one project in my server. And the public folder do not makes any problem for me.so i think its not important to remove the public folder

Answer (score 1):

Finally i solved the issue.

```
public function addAuction(){
        AuctionModel::addAuctions(Input::except(array('_token')));
        return Redirect::to('admin/auctionlist');
}
```

its in laravel 4.

in laravel 5
it should be

```
return $this->redirect()->route('some-route-name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `return redirect`. And why messing your routing with functions? Just rule it to use the function in your controller:

routing

```
Route::post('admin/auctionlist','AdminController@addAuction');
```

controller

```
public function addAuction(){
        AuctionModel::addAuctions(Input::except(array('_token')));
         return redirect('admin/auctionlist');
}
```

Comment: Its is not working Getting error as 
ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /var/www/html/vishal/site/bootstrap/compiled.php:5751
in my log.

Comment: The action of your post must be "admin/auctionlist", not "auctionlist". We ok with that? And of course method must be `post`

Comment: i solve the problem by
return Redirect::to('admin/auctionlist');
thanks for your help.